# How can I change my wireless card's regulatory domain (Dbm higher than 30)?

Tags: networking, wireless, binary, nic

For educational purposes we are trying to change the wireless devices txpower higher than domain regulations per country...

To operate outside of specific bands or power levels, we know you have to change the regulatory domain on a given card, but we're not sure how to do it.

We've located the `regulatory.bin` file but need help changing and editing the information within this binary file!

*How should we proceed?*

Currently Using Older D-Link Corp. AirPlus G DWL-G122 Wireless Adapter(rev.B1) [Ralink RT2571

Comment: You might want to specify your wireless card, or that you are willing to get one that allows this.  Some just won't let you, or make it incredibly hard.  Others make it oh so simple.

Comment: Currently Using Older D-Link Corp. AirPlus G DWL-G122 Wireless Adapter(rev.B1) [Ralink RT2571]  but I have several cards to use!

Comment: This binary file gets compiled from a source db.txt file which contains information about the regulations in different countries. It is compiled into the binary format and signed with a RSA private key, the public key of which is embedded into crda, which takes care of supplying the Linux kernel with updates to that file.

Answer (score 3):

From a terminal:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano, leafpad or kate if you haven't gedit. Change the only non-commented line to:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Or whatever country code you desire. Proofread, save and close the text editor. Unload and reload the wireless driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Or whatever your wireless driver is. Check `dmesg` for a line similar to this:

```
cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: IS
```

Comment: Great Answer... Except this does not allow power levels above 30dbm... All this does is implement another country codes **(domain)** regulations!

Comment: I think if you choose china you will be able to use over 30 DBm

Comment: Wasn't that your question? How to change the regulatory domain?

Comment: @chili555 If I misinterpreted the question, that's my fault.  I did a big edit, because I thought this is what he wanted and it was up for closure.